# CKEditor is stripping / removing tags =(

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, tags, ckeditor

I am new to configuring CKEditor on **Drupal 7**, and even with the UI, it has always been a pain. I am trying to have it to stop stripping / removing tags, specifically - code, pre, ins del, blockquote, q, dl, dd, dt. I have a test page which I use to test my site's styles and these are getting removed in both Full and Filtered. Grrrr...

Keep in mind I have no idea what I am doing here. Please help me figure this out so I do not waste another day on this. =(

**ACF's extra allowed content**

I have added the following there:

```
br; div; span; header; footer; section; aside; figure; a; img; strong; em; h1; h2; h3; h4; h5; h6; ins; del; cite; q; blockquote; code; pre; table; tr; td; th; thead; tfoot; caption; legend; col; ul; ol; li; dl; dd; dt;</code>
```

**config.js**

I have found config.js and added the following to get it to stop stripping out tags.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) 
{
// Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
// config.language = 'fr';
// config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
config.allowedContent = 'br div span;' + 
    'header footer section aside figure;' + 
    'a[!href]; img[!src,alt,width,height];strong em h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6;' +
     'ins del cite q blockquote code pre;' +
     'table tr td th thead tfoot caption legend col;' + 
     'ul ol li dl dd dt';
config.extraAllowedContent = ' br div(*) span(*);' + 
    'header footer section aside figure;' + 
    'a[!href]; img[!src,alt,width,height];strong em h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6;' +
    'ins del cite q blockquote code pre;' +
     'table tr td th thead tfoot caption legend col;' + 
     'ul ol li dl dd dt';
};
```

Comment: Surely someone has used the CKEditor module and knows how to get this working properly?

Answer (score 0):

There are no many places to see:

1. Content .- Make sure the content is correct, that all tags are closed properly and have chosen the correct input filter. To rule out problems, select Full HTML.
2. CKEditor.- In the CKEditor module page says:

> Note for CKEditor 4.1+ users If you are using CKEditor 4.1+, you may need to adjust Advanced Content Filter settings. You can do this by editing the CKEditor profiles and going to the Advanced Content Filter section, where it is possible to disable ACF completely as well as set "Extra allowed content".

Try disabling it, in order to discard one possible cause. Make sure to follow the format rules of the Extra allowed content.

```
object[width,height];param[name,value];embed[*];
```

ACF will filter all tools that you don't select as the "Current Toolbar".

3. Filters.- If you chose Filter HTML make sure that you add all the tags in the "Allowed HTML Tags" section in configuration, and/or you don't have any other module that add another filter option.

Comment: This is not enough. I've tquadriple-checked each and every point here, and still, on *Full* CKEditor profile, there are `<i>` and `<a>` tags stripped. The *Full HTML* Text format does not remove anything here. I don't know how to look further now. BTW, using CKEditor 4.4.3/full-all from *cdn.ckeditor.com*